# Align itemize bullet to text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize

I am looking for a command to align text to the itemize's bullet.

```
{\addtolength{\leftskip}{10mm} 
\textbf{Short text in here}
\begin{itemize}
\item A description of..
\item Another description of..
\end{itemize}
\par
```

My text and items are nicely moved 10mm towards right due to the \leftskip{10mm} but it won't align just right.

Now, I want the bullet from my item to left align with my "Short text in here". I need a command to offset my items a little to the right. Is there any way to handle that?

I hope this makes sense. Otherwise, don't hesitate to ask once again! :-)

Answer (score 2):

With `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \addtolength{\leftskip}{10mm}
  \textbf{Short text in here}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\dimexpr\parindent+10mm+0.5\labelwidth\relax]
    \item A description of..
    \item Another description of..
  \end{itemize}
  \par
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, I don't understand some thing. May be instead of `\textbf` you can use a `\section*`. Then you can write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem,showframe} %% show frame just for demo
\begin{document}
  \addtolength{\leftskip}{10mm}
  \section*{Short text in here}
  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\dimexpr10mm+0.5\labelwidth\relax]
    \item A description of..
    \item Another description of
  \end{itemize}
  \par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the `wide` key gives a simpler syntax. Besides I wonder whether the O.P. wnats the bullets to be 10mm from the (text) left margin. In the latter case a simple `\noindent` before \textbf{Short text in here} and a `[wide=\leftskip]` would do.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: We are on the right track though I now ran into compiling problems. 
While compiling it says: You can't use `\dimexpr' in horizontal mode. [  \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=\dimexpr]

@Bernard: Yes, I want the text to be offset 10 mm from the left margin.

Comment: @user3389689 May be you need to update your tex distribution. I don't get any errors. You may also try `\begin{itemize}[wide=\leftskip]` as told by Bernard. Put a `\noindent` before `\textbf{Short text in here}` though.